# How to access Backbone Model properties in a Handlebar template

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

If there is a Backbone Model called `Person`, which has properties `firstName`, `lastName`. Usually, access to it is like `person.get('firstName')` and `person.get('lastName')`.

How do I do a similar thing in a Handlebar template, where a `person` has been exposed to the context.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you render the Handlebars template, you need to pass in the attributes of the model. The recommended way to do this is to call `Model.toJSON`, which returns a copy of the the model's internal `attributes` hash.

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
var rendered = template({ person: model.toJSON() });
```

In the template you can access the context by the property name.

```
<span>{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}</span>
```

Comment: Got it. So the idea is to expose JSON to the template instead of Backbone models.

Comment: @AkshayRawat, `Model.toJSON` is named a bit funnily, because what it returns it's not really JSON, just a normal javascript object. If you wanted actual JSON, you would have to call `JSON.stringify(model.toJSON())` - but what Handlebars wants is a normal object.

Comment: The `toJSON` name isn't really Backbone's fault, the name is specified by [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON#toJSON()_method).

Comment: @muistooshort, yeah, I'm aware of that, which, now that I think of it, makes the `.toJSON()` redundant in my previous comment. It's still one of those naming conventions that I wish weren't one.

Answer (score 6):

Actually I've so many places with .toJSON so I've developed a Handlebars modification to handle Backbone Models:

https://gist.github.com/4710958

It will check if a value is instance of Backbone.Model and if it is it will invoke the .get() method.

Backbone.Model should be global in order to use it.

```
{{ user.address.street }}
```

Will be parsed as:

```
user.get("adress").street
```

Comment: Does this still work with HandleBars v1.3.0 ? I've put your snippet in my app.js but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Handlebars anymore so I don't know. Do you see any error on the console? If you do, we can keep talking about it at https://gist.github.com/amatiasq/4710958